# Closed Question: Where would a robotic engineer work?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I am wondering about the reason given for closing the question: [Where would a robotic engineer work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7933/where-would-a-robotic-engineer-work-closed). It was closed as "too localized".

> "This question would only be relevant
>   to a small geographic area, a specific
>   moment in time, or an extraordinarily
>   narrow situation that is not generally
>   applicable to the worldwide audience
>   of the internet."

I was one of those who answered this question. I work for an international supplier of industrial robots. I do not consider a robotics career to be limited in time or geography. I interact with robot users and colleagues from around the world.

I am not necessarily arguing to reopen the question. I just want to understand the reason for closing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These sites are typically about the *application:* In this case "Electronics and Robotics." It is a site for practitioners talking *about* the subject. That doesn't typically include "soft topics" like schooling, or lifestyles, or employment/career questions. These sites don't typically include career talk and certainly not job placement. That's probably the main reason this question was closed, even if the reason cited wasn't exact.

The *too localized*-reason is likely in reaction to the employment request. It's really localized in the sense that it is only useful to *that* particular user in *that* specific time frame, and "who is hiring" is of no use to anyone who comes after a short period of time. You could argue that the author was asking a more general question about the industry but it was hard to tell from the lack of detail.

The question is really hard to answer without any details. The result was each answer seemed to be addressing a different question. Perhaps if the question included some of those details and background, and it was more generally relevant to practitioners and the industry, the *jist* of what the user was asking could have been accommodated. They are welcome to try again.

Comment: @JimC, Robert has explained the reasoning that was used exactly. We are very happy you have taken the time to come to the site, and I hope you continue to contribute. A regularly redirect users from http://www.reddit.com/r/ECE/ when they have a specific question about a circuit, when you need job advice, a couple people have actually found jobs from other members on the site. @robertcartaino, thanks for swooping in to explain.

Answer (score -2):

So **"about a job title"** is too specific, but **"[identify this logo](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7637/can-you-identify-this-logo/7640#7640)"** is not?... How hypocritical. The question was perfectly fine IMO.